# redshift spectrum type conversion from String to Varchar

Tags: pyspark, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, parquet, amazon-redshift-spectrum

When I scan the data from S3 using a Glue crawler I get this schema:

```
{id: integer, value: String}
```

This is because Spark writes data back in `String` type and not `varchar` type. Although there is a VarcharType in spark. (See: [VarcharType — PySpark master documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.types.VarcharType.html))

The problem is I need the data in Redshift as a Spectrum query in `VarcharType` only as my BI tool is not capable of reading `string` type data.

If I use `Create External Table` I get all null values in the table. Only If I change it to an internal table the issue solves. But, I really need it as a Spectrum query. Any suggestions to convert the string type to `varchartype`?